# How do I close Microsoft Edge without Admin rights if the "First Welcome" window of Microsoft Edge pops up and icon-right-click-close does not work?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I am on a terminal server for which I do not have the rights to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> and which I cannot just restart so that I cannot force the pop up window of Microsoft Edge to close, after I started it.

I thought I would leave the icon in the status bar for some time and deal with it later, but I see it whenever I switch between the windows, and it takes some time and nerves that Micrsoft Edge cares so much about me.

I cannot close it if I:

- right click close on the icon of the status bar.
  [image]
- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> into the overview of all tabs:
  [image]

How do I close Microsoft Edge without admin rights if the "First Welcome" window of Microsoft Edge pops up and right click close on the icon does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into it by chance. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It becomes the browser again and you can close it as always:

[image]